# Drupal - show popup on front-page load only one time

Tags: jquery, drupal-6, popup

using jquery, cck and views I can show a simple popup when the front page is loaded. (to point up a special event...)

With my simple script the popup appears every time I visit the front page, but I would change this behavior: it must appear only one time per session.

Any advice?
Cookie? Global variables?

What's the best solution?

Thanks
Bye

### UPDATE

Resolved using jquery plugin "cooquery" with a temporary cookie. This solution satisfy me enough!

[link text](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cooquery)

Comment: Hey, does "session" mean "connected user" in your case? If yes, I think you should be able to store any value you want in the user's data property (I'm not 100% sur).

Comment: The popup must be seen also by anonymous user (session isn't probably the correct word). I thinking, but I'm not sure, that the only way is to create and read a cookie through jquery. I'll try to study in deep drupal's cookies management